# Assembly code can't handle negative integers

Tags: assembly, x86-64

My assembly code consists of two parts, one called A.s and another called B.s.

A.s is my 'main' where I stream output to the terminal.

B.s can not handle negative integers, and also displays the 'Welcome msg' twice.

Here is the code;

B.s code

```
some code above this-----------------
LoopNextInt:
    movq    $buffInPtr, %r10
    movq    $buffIn, %r9
    addq    (%r10), %r9
    xorq    %r8, %r8

    addq    (%r9),%r8

    cmpq    $63, (%r9)
    je  inImage

    cmpq    $' ', (%r9)
    je  retNeg

    cmpq    $'-', (%r9)
    je  negSignFound

    cmpb    $'0', (%r9)
    jl  retNeg

    cmpb    $'9', (%r9)
    jg  retNeg

    movzbq  (%r9),%r11

    imulq   $10, %rax
    subq    $'0', %r11  #asci -> dec tal
    addq    %r11, %rax
    //addq  $1, (%r10)
    incq    buffInPtr
    //addq  $1, %r9
    incq    buffIn

    jmp     LoopNextInt

some code below this-----------------
then comes this ---------------     
fillOutBuffWithChars:
    movq    $buffOutPtr,%r9
    cmpq    $63, (%r9)  
    je      outImage                
    movzbq  (%rdi), %r8             
    movb    %r8b, (%r10)                
    cmpq    $0, (%rdi)              
    je      zeroInStringFoundz

    addq    $1,%rdi
    addq    $1,%r10
    //addq  $1,%r9
    incq    buffOutPtr
    jmp     fillOutBuffWithChars

zeroInStringFoundz: 
    ret
```

A test run from the program;

```
Start. Enter 5 numbers, both negative and pos numbers.
Start. Enter 5 numbers, both negative and pos numbers.
5 1 3 6 -5        
5+1+3+6+0=15
5
125
End
Made by Jozo
```

I noticed, if I use a sentence that is smaller, like, " Enter 5 numbers ", it will not print it double.

EDIT; Removed unnecessary code so new users can see the problem more easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cmpq $0, (%rdi)` should be `cmpb $0, (%rdi)` or simply `cmp $0, %r8b` since the byte is already loaded anyway. Given that you compare a quadword instead of a byte, it will not find the end of the string which then causes `outImage` to be invoked from inside `putText` and so the text is printed already. But then you call `outImage` in `main` again, hence the doubled output.

You have the same problem in `LoopNextInt`, where all your quadword comparisons should be byte sized. As it is, `negSignFound` is never reached which in turn means `revInt` is never reached either.

PS: Learn to use a debugger and comment your code.